# google scripts search ID columns for matches then search columns for non matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Here I am trying to match product number and then search for non matching features. So in the following example we see in COL A- Product ID, COL B- Features, COL C- Product ID, COL D- Features. I want to compare the columns A-B with columns C-D. I was able to match the entire cell but I am wanting to get more granular and match words within the cell. So with the example below I would like to see results for product 12345 because it is missing the "Medium" feature. Also we would get results from 54321 as it is missing the feature "good".

**COL A   |  COL B    |  COL C  | COL D |

Prod ID |  features | Prod ID  | features**

12345 | fast and slow and medium | 12345 | slow
12345 | fast and slow           | 12345 | fast
12345 | fast and slow           | 12345 | fast
54321 | hard and good           | 12345 | hard
54321 | hard and good           | 12345 | hard
12345 | fast and slow           | 12345 | fast

Example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRnVIHj8ekDOzYdFyv0PSGCynh91CPWiA5LxYV52McDH4nTsUp4faP7Iw6P44xG1HUavuwAT8wfXjaA/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

So far I have the following script with 2 functions and it appears to make results if the cells are in the exact format but many are not. I do not need 2 functions but it was my attempt at getting this accomplished.

**The question is: How can I first match the columns A & C with an exact match, Then if column B has any word that is not in Column D print the results into COL E:F**

Thansk for any Help.

```js
function checkProduct() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("A Data - Formatted")
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var lookup = s.getRange(2,1,lr-1,5).getValues();
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("B Data - Formatted") 
  var lr1=s1.getLastRow()
  var range = s1.getRange(2,1,lr1-1,5).getValues();
  var s3=ss.getSheetByName("Matches")
  s3.getRange("A2:F").clear();
  var lookupRange = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
     var  test=lookup[i][0]
         if(lookup[i][0]==range[j][0]){
           lookupRange.push([range[j][0],range[j][1],lookup[i][0],lookup[i][1],]);
     }}}
   s3.getRange(2,1,lookupRange.length,4).setValues(lookupRange); 
}
                             
function checknoMatch() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Matches")
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var lookup = s.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2).getValues();
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Matches") 
  var lr1=s1.getLastRow()
  var range = s1.getRange(2,3,lr1-1,2).getValues();
  var s3=ss.getSheetByName("Differences")
   s3.getRange("A2:F").clear();
  var lookupRange = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
     var  test=lookup[i][0]
         if(lookup[i][0] == range[j][0] && lookup[i][1] != range[j][1]){
           lookupRange.push([range[j][0],range[j][1],lookup[i][0],lookup[i][1],]);
     }}}
   s3.getRange(2,1,lookupRange.length,4).setValues(lookupRange); 
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? Thanks for any help is not a question.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: updated the question...

Comment: How do you want the words in column B that are not in column D placed in columns E and F?

Comment: at this point I would like to see COL A,COL,B & Col D just get copied to COL E/F/G or placed in a new sheet- either would work this would display the item ID, the missing features, and then the existing features frmo D

Comment: The question I just asked remains unanswered?

Comment: Or perhaps you've changed the question.  I don't know which is it?

Comment: I have created an example spreadsheet- perhaps that will be helpful - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRnVIHj8ekDOzYdFyv0PSGCynh91CPWiA5LxYV52McDH4nTsUp4faP7Iw6P44xG1HUavuwAT8wfXjaA/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Matching and Non Matching

```
function getMatching(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(vA[i][0]==vA[i][2]){
      vA[i][4]=vA[i][0];
      vA[i][6]=vA[i][3];
      vA[i][5]=getNonMatching({col2:vA[i][1],col4:vA[i][3]}); 
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).setValues(vA);
}

function getNonMatching(sObj){
  if(sObj.col2 && sObj.col4){
    var vA2=sObj.col2.split(" ");
    var vA4=sObj.col4.split(" ");
    vA4.push('and');//You can push other insignificant word into vA4 to keep them out of the output string.
    var s='';
    var n=0;
    for(var i=0;i<vA2.length;i++){
      if(vA4.indexOf(vA2[i])==-1){
        if(n>0) {
          s+=' ';
        }
        s+=vA2[i];
        n++;
      }
    }
    return s;
  }else{
    return 'Error: Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Spreadsheet Before Running:

[image]

Spreadsheet After Running:

[image]